# Biblatex: getting uniquename to include incollection editors

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` with the `biber` backend and the citation style `biblatex-juardiss`.  I am using the option `uniquename=allfull` to avoid ambigious author names.  My problem is that the uniquename list includes authors and editors from `@BOOK`, `@ARTICLE` and `@COMMENTARY`.  But the editors of `@INCOLLECTION` are not included in the uniquename list.  `\value{uniquename}` from an `@INCOLLECTION` editor always returns zero.

I tried the following minimal code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}

@BOOK{werner,
  author = {Werner, Dennis},
  title = {Title of the Book}
}

@INCOLLECTION{werner2,
  editor = {Schneider, Uwe AND Werner, Hans},
  title = {Title of the Article},
  booktitle = {Title of the Book},
  Author = {Tester, Hans}
}


@COMMENTARY{werner3,
  editor = {Schneider, Uwe AND Werner, Hans},
  title = {Title of the Article}
}

\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, left=1.9cm, right=2.1cm, top=1.2cm, bottom=2.3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authortitle,
uniquename=allfull
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{lit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
    \ifentrytype{incollection}{\addcomma\addspace\printnames{editor}}{}%
    }
    
\DeclareNameFormat[incollection]{editor}{%
  \iffootnote{%
    \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#6}{}{#7}}%
    \or
      \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last-init}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
    \or
      \usebibmacro{name:first-last-init}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
    \fi%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
    }
    {\mkbibemph{%
      \iffirstinits%
        {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
        {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
      \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
    }}%
}%

\begin{document}

1\footcite{werner}
2\footcite{werner2}
% 3\footcite{werner3}

\end{document}
```

As a result I get:

> 1 Werner, Title of the Book.
>
> 2 Tester, “Title of the Article”, Schneider and Werner.

This result is abmibious since both Werners are differnet people.

If I cite the `werner3`, I get:

> 1 D. Werner, Title of the Book.
>
> 2 Tester, “Title of the Article”, Schneider and Werner.
>
> 3 Schneider and H. Werner, Title of the Article.

How do I get the editors of `@INCOLLECTION` included in the uniquename list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name disambiguation only considers names in the `labelname` list. For your `@incollection` entry the editors aren't part of `labelname` because the `author` field is available. One way around this is to cross-reference a `@collection` entry in which the editors form the `labelname`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{werner,
  author = {Werner, Dennis},
  title = {Title of the Book}}
@COLLECTION{schneider,
  options = {skipbib},
  editor = {Schneider, Uwe AND Werner, Hans},
  title = {Title of the Book}}
@INCOLLECTION{tester,
  title = {Title of the Article},
  author = {Tester, Hans},
  crossref = {schneider}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle,uniquename=allfull,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\newbibmacro*{in:labelname}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{\printnames{labelname}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}{}{%
       \printnames{labelname}%
       \setunit{\nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
     \ifentrytype{incollection}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{in:labelname}{\thefield{crossref}}}{}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler.\footcite{werner} Filler.\footcite{tester}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `mincrossrefs=1` setting ensures that the cross-referenced entry is considered in name disambiguation. To suppress this entry in the bibliography, we set `skipbib=true` in the `bib` file.